# Query on Elastic Search

Tags: elasticsearch

I am planning to use Elastic search for one of my new search tool.. till now we have been using plain lucene... today we dont search passed value against any specific field(s), we are always doing match_all option. meaning if someone typed "xyz" then our query is simply find "xyz" wherever it matched.

my question is, is it advisable to use match_all option or we should search against some predefined fields? I read some where it take lot of CPU and memory.. but I am looking for some specific reason which can be used as strong reason to avoid same in elastic..

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The `match_all` query is great to get started, or to find *something* that matches, but it will only bring you so far. Most of the time, the relevance needs to be better than `match_all` can provide, because `match_all` threats all fields equally. Things like:

- make `title` more important than `description`
- use a different `analyzer` for different fields
- make prefix matches more relevant

..require (`boolean`) `match` queries. I could go on, but you get the gist.

Comment: yeah got it.. but will there be any performance issue if I opt for match_all??
which one will be faster?? technically if we see then obviously match_all will be slow than specific fields but need some solid evidence to support the statement.

Comment: If performance is your only consideration, `match_all` is a good choice. Its simplicity makes it fast.